# Facebook open graph choose share location

Tags: facebook, share-open-graph

Is it possible to add option for share location somewhere in the code using share_open_graph?

```js
FB.ui({
                    method: 'share_open_graph',
                    action_type: 'og.shares',
                    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                        object: {
                            'og:url': url,
                            'og:title': title,
                            'og:description': description,
                            'og:image': thumb
                        }
                    })
                });
```

[image]

Comment: any updates on this?